# Drupal still working without .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I'm having a weird problem with my site.

Recently I found that one domain (not mine) was pointing to my IP. My IP hosts a system on Drupal 7 (LAMP) and Ubuntu. My site (still in development and only working in my IP) was already indexed by Google with that other domain name, so I decided to block this site with a simple ".htaccess" trick...

I can't block the "intruder" site using this and that snippet... Frustrated after many tries I wrote some garbage to see if something happened... but everything was still working. Then I erase the .htaccess file in Drupal root... but everything is still working until now.

I've been developing almost 10 years ago, managing small VPSs a few years ago, and when you make a tiny mistake in .htaccess then nothing works! And that's ok! So, as you can imagine i'm lost.

Here is the result when I search for all .htaccess files:
[image]

My Drupal is installed in /var/www/html

Using the devel module this is part of my phpinfo (as you can see .htaccess is not in Drupal root):

[image]

Possibly, I'm making a very stupid mistake, but i've been on this like 2 hours and right now I don't have more places to look at.

I restarted Apache, asumming some kind of unknown cache in the .htaccess file. I also restarted the VPS (Digital Ocean)... No .htaccess file, but my Drupal installation is still working...

I'm missing something terribly... please help!

UPDATE: Every page is still working... also nice URLs.
UPDATE 2: I'm attaching how looks 'sites-enabled' folder from Apache with only one file and it's contents.

[image: sites-enabled folder and 000-default.conf contents]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have some rewrite rules in your VirtualHost configuration and/or apache configuration files. Check all files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` for any RewriteRules.

Comment: I'll check this "sites-enabled" folder again. Probably I forgot it... Thanks!

Comment: Nothing still... I'm going to do a grep to find rewrites (if any) that Drupal does to look for the "hidden" htaccess file... Because rewrites are happening somehow. Thanks again Ricardo.

Answer (score 1):

Even if .htaccess file is not present home page will load , if you want to stop indexing by google , disallow it in robots.txt file . also u can make an htacesss popup password protection too.Also try to ping the url and see  is dev/Production server is  giving response if the url's are same .

Comment: Ok, my mistake: Every page is still working. Even nice URLs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well... Finally I discovered my own error.

I put my rewrite configuration inside /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, probably I had some troubles setting nice-urls at beggining and then I forgot to enabled it properly :/

I know Drupal can't have nice URLs without these rewrite rules, so they should be somewhere. So I search for the string "RewriteEngine on" and "apache2.conf" came as a result (see the image).

Now it's solved. My apologies.

[image]

Comment: Super! :) I mentioned in my comment that it could be in apache configuration files also but I assumed it would most likely be in `sites-enabled` ;)

Comment: Reading again your answer you are right... You deserve the half of the prize I think... but for knowledge I think my answer gives a useful way to identify where are these rewrite rules... Anyhow... You answered first so I will give you the points you deserve... Rules are rules :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put

```
Deny from all
Allow from your.ip.address
```

in the .htaccess file.  That will prevent everyone except you from accessing the site.

Ref: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

There is also a header which you can add like so:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag noindex,noarchive
```

This requests that search engines not index or archive the content.  If access is denied, it won't be necessary.  Be sure to remove it when the site goes live.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=en